# Conditional expanding group aggregation pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For some data preprocessing I have a huge dataframe where I need historical performance within groups. However since it is for a predictive model that runs a week before the target I cannot use any data that happened in that week in between. There are a variable number of rows per day per group which means I cannot always discard the last 7 values by using a shift on the expanding functions, I have to somehow condition on the datetime of rows before it. I can write my own function to apply on the groups however this is usually very slow in my experience (albeit flexible). This is how I did it without conditioning on date and just looking at previous records:

```
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df_gr['old_col'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding(5).mean().shift(1))
```

The 5 represents that I want at least a sample size of 5 or to put it to NaN.

Small example with aggr_mean looking at the mean of all samples within group A at least a week earlier:

```
group | dt       | value  | aggr_mean
A     | 01-01-16 | 5      | NaN
A     | 03-01-16 | 4      | NaN
A     | 08-01-16 | 12     | 5 (only looks at first row)
A     | 17-01-16 | 11     | 7 (looks at first three rows since all are 
                               at least a week earlier)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data please? [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah forgot to do it, just added it :)

Answer (score 5):

***new answer***
using @JulienMarrec's better example

```
dt           group  value   
2016-01-01     A      5
2016-01-03     A      4
2016-01-08     A     12
2016-01-17     A     11
2016-01-04     B     10
2016-01-05     B      5
2016-01-08     B     12
2016-01-17     B     11
```

Condition `df` to be more useful

```
d1 = df.drop('group', 1)
d1.index = [df.group, df.groupby('group').cumcount().rename('gidx')]
d1
```

[image]

create a custom function that does what old answer did.  Then apply it within `groupby`

```
def lag_merge_asof(df, lag):
    d = df.set_index('dt').value.expanding().mean()
    d.index = d.index + pd.offsets.Day(lag)
    d = d.reset_index(name='aggr_mean')
    return pd.merge_asof(df, d)

d1.groupby(level='group').apply(lag_merge_asof, lag=7)
```

[image]

we can get some formatting with this

```
d1.groupby(level='group').apply(lag_merge_asof, lag=7) \
    .reset_index('group').reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

---

***old answer***

create a `lookback` dataframe by offsetting the dates by 7 days, then use it to [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

```
lookback = df.set_index('dt').value.expanding().mean()

lookback.index += pd.offsets.Day(7)
lookback = lookback.reset_index(name='aggr_mean')

lookback
```

[image]

```
pd.merge_asof(df, lookback, left_on='dt', right_on='dt')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do `merge_asof` on both `['group', 'dt']`? Because OP's requirement is do to it within groups (not extremely clear because the sample data has only one group, but it's written in the intro)

Comment: I'm working on that now... trying not to fall asleep as well ;-)

Comment: As I unfortunately didn't state clearly enough is that there could be days with multiple rows which the resampling method doesn't allow for, I could use your old method in a similar fashion though right?

Comment: Ahh, there is an answer.  I'm just too tired to do it at the moment.  It could be left as an exercise for you.  I don't have to set the index.  I can leave `dt` in the data part of the dataframe and track the index I have.  That should be enough of a clue.

Comment: +1 For the record, I checked and your "new answer" seems to work even if there are multiple rows for same date.  A mean value gets merged onto multiple rows for same later date and and if multiple rows per date all need to be included in the mean function, that's done too.

Answer (score 4):

Given this dataframe where I added another group in order to more clearly see what's happening:

```
dt           group  value                               
2016-01-01     A      5
2016-01-03     A      4
2016-01-08     A     12
2016-01-17     A     11
2016-01-04     B     10
2016-01-05     B      5
2016-01-08     B     12
2016-01-17     B     11
```

Let's load it:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, sep='\s+', parse_dates=True)
```

Now we can use a groupby, resample daily, and do an shift that 7 days, and take the mean:

```
x = df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda gp: gp.resample('1D').mean().shift(7).expanding().mean())
```

Now you can merge `left` that back into your df:

```
merged = df.reset_index().set_index(['group','dt']).join(x, rsuffix='_aggr_mean', how='left')
merged
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a nice approach, but does this resampling approach still work if there are several rows with the same dt?

Comment: I didn't know that was a requirement... No it would mess up the weights. You'd have to to do a mix between my answer (groupby, because you want to do it by groups but no resample instead shift(freq='7D')) and @piRSquared's merge_asof

Comment: Thanks, sorry I wasn't clear enough, should have also added it in the example.